# skip first and last item in the list in python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
iplist = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3', '4.4.4.4', '5.5.5.5']
```

How do i skip first ,last entry and run a for loop in items between ?
I am aware of skipping first([1:]) and last([:-1]) separate but not together.

Comment: Combine the two - `iplist[1:-1]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got the answer:

```
for ip in iplist[1:][:-1]:
 #Do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use -ve slicing -> Skip 1st element & last element

```
iplist[1:-1]
```

For loop will look like this:

```
for i in iplist[1:-1]:
    print(i)
```

Output will be:

```
2.2.2.2 
3.3.3.3
4.4.4.4
```